# Add member to openfire server

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire

I am using `openfire` and `xmpp` framework for mycchat application. I am using

```
XMPPJID *newBuddy = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"test@localhost"];
[self.xmppRoster addUser:newBuddy withNickname:@"user1"];
```

for adding new member but new member is not add to `server`.
In setupStream method code:

```
 xmppRosterStorage = [[XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage alloc] init];
 xmppRosterStorage = [[XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage alloc] initWithInMemoryStore];

xmppRoster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:xmppRosterStorage];
xmppRoster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:xmppRosterStorage
                                              dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[xmppRoster addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
xmppRoster.autoFetchRoster = YES;
xmppRoster.autoAcceptKnownPresenceSubscriptionRequests = YES;
```

How can I add member?

Answer (score 1):

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) XMPPStream *xmppStream;    
@property (nonatomic, readonly) XMPPRoster *xmppRoster;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) XMPPRosterMemoryStorage *xmppRosterStorage;
```

In `setupStream` method setup a `XMPPStream` and `XMPPRoaster`

```
_xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc]init];
_xmppStream.enableBackgroundingOnSocket = YES;
_xmppRosterStorage = [[XMPPRosterMemoryStorage alloc] init];
_xmppRoster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:_xmppRosterStorage];
[_xmppRoster activate:_xmppStream];
[_xmppRoster  addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

For adding new `contact`

```
[_xmppRoster addUser:jid withNickname:nickName];
```

After accepting by the recipient , new contact will be reflected in your roaster list

Comment: If u have any query let me know

Comment: Thanx for your reply. How can I add member using registerWithElements method?

Comment: Add member means new user registration , r8?

Comment: Add contact and new user registration are different cases,i think here u asking about adding contacts to our roater

Comment: I want to add new user in my open fire server so how can I add them? Which method is doing that job?

Comment: Cool. ask that as separate question, i ll answer